# Given a website loaded in an iframe, how to determine the file sizes of content downloaded in it

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to build a page that loads a website in an iframe, and also shows the filesizes of all the contents downloaded as part of the iframe:

all the images, html, js and anything else that was loaded as part of that iframe.

Is there a way to get that information with javascript?

Comment: Why would it matter? It's a different resource.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the information by using ajax with the path of site files

For example, if you send a request to Google url, you will receive Google's html tags